# "No Such Module" for created cocoapod

Tags: swift, objective-c, flutter, xcode, cocoapods

I have created a pod successfully and uploaded on github and cocoapods (https://github.com/marwamelfeky/AmwalyPod) . Then created a project to use. The Pod installed successfully but when importing it No such module error Occurred . The pod depends on Flutter and written with Objective-C . I added spec.dependency and the validation of specs passed. What causes this error?

I expect the pod to be imported successfully and use it in my xcode project

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.